# Как сделать чтоб при сворачивании и разворачивании приложение запускалось не с нуля

Tags: java, android

Ребят я задавал вопрос но неправильно его составил ...Есть приложение которое определяет моё местоположение и отправляет данные на удаленную БД `Mysql`.Я на все действия поставил логи и слежу за поведением приложения .
В  приложении есть 2 кнопки .Первая при нажатии   получат данные и отправляет их интервалом в БД и становится невидимой вот пример

```
final TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int i=0;
            i++;
            System.out.println("Request  N +" +i);

            Sender s=new Sender(MainActivity.this,urlAddress,lat,lot);
            s.execute();
        }
    };
     final Timer timer =new Timer();

    saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       //timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask,0,3000);
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask,0,8000);
            saveBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }
    });
```

Вторая кнопка отменяет действие 1 кнопки и делает её видимой

```
 removeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    timer.cancel();
                }catch (Exception e){
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,e +"", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                saveBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
```

Но  стоит мне свернуть и развернуть приложение то

1)Невидимая кнопка становится видна

2)Я не могу отменить действие 1 кнопки Как будто я не развернул приложение а сново запустил его ,и потерял контроль над старым действием .Прошу Помочь .Спасибо !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо сохранять состояние приложения через объект [Bundle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).
После активации приложения параметры, которые Вы сохранили в Bundle, можно будет использовать для восстановления состояния приложения.

Comment: Спасибо Денис!Очень благодраен ВАМ!